# Как разделить видео на части по 2 секунды на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, видео

В ходе работы, мне понадобилось разделить большое количество видеозаписей на части по 2 секунды, таким образом, чтобы создавалась папка с названием первоначальной видеозаписи, например, "videoname", и в ней содержались все эти "кусочки" по 2 секунды с названием, например: "videoname_1.avi", "videoname_2.avi" и т.д. Есть видеозаписи с расширением .mp4 и .webm. Не очень понимаю как это лучше осуществить.  Использую python 3.6 на windows 10. Подскажите, пожалуйста, заранее благодарю.

Comment: Никак! Если бы у вас был Linux - то  ffmpeg справился с задачей прямо из  пыхтона.

Comment: вызывайте ffmpeg из питона. Win или Linux - значения не имеет. И если потом эти куски клеить, то можно без промежуточных файлов обойтись

Comment: @vitidev, а че, на вендовсе ффмпег тоже имеется, и его можно вызвать из  пыхтона? Я просто уверен, что это не юзерфрендли путь, или нет?!

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk конечно есть. Обычный exe, который можно положить в PATH или еще как достукиваться. А в питоне вызывать всякие сишные вещи через биндинги/врапперы норма. Собственно за это (практичность) питон и любят.

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk спасибо за совет! Пытаюсь запустить код через командную строку, но не знаю почему у меня выводит ошибку: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл. Хотя код, видео и ffmpeg находятся в одной папке